# I could not find the status of tomcat server after running the application

Tags: java, eclipse

```java
package com.vikasreddy.springweb.MavenWebApp;

import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import jakarta.servlet.Servlet;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws LifecycleException
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
        Context context = tomcat.addContext(" ", null);
        Tomcat.addServlet(context, "h1", (Servlet) new HelloServlet());
        context.addServletMappingDecoded("/hello", "h1");
    }
}
```

I could not find the status of Tomcat server after running the demo application through maven project in console. Could anyone help me in finding the error? I am beginner. Could anyone help me? I have added the server in servers tab of Eclipse.

Comment: "through maven project in console" What does that mean? How would someone reproduce what that is? Were you launching from Maven or the Servers View?

Comment: You are running Tomcat from within Eclipse, correct? Then, after you launch Tomcat, you run the code in your question, correct? Now what exactly is your problem? Does the code [in your question] not do what you expect it to do? If not, then what does it actually do and what do you want it to do?